# What is the best way to manage multithreading in JavaFX 8?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to find an efficient way to influence the shape and the content of the JavaFX GUI elements, such as simple `Pane`, with use of multithreading. Let's say I have a simple `Pane`, on which I display filled `Circle`s at the given itervals of time, and I want to have the posibility to answer to them, e.g. by hitting the corresponding key. So far, for this purpose,  I tried to use class with the implementation of `Runnable` interface and creation of classic `Thread` object in it, in order to add and/or remove elements from the external JavaFX `Pane`, which was passed to that "thread class" in its constructor parameter from the main `Application` class. Say, both classes, 1) application and 2) thread class, looks like this:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ClassApplication extends Application {

    private Pane pane;

    public Parent createContent() {

        /* layout */
        BorderPane layout = new BorderPane();

        /* layout -> center */
        pane = new Pane();
        pane.setMinWidth(250);
        pane.setMaxWidth(250);
        pane.setMinHeight(250);
        pane.setMaxHeight(250);
        pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #000000;");

        /* layout -> center -> pane */
        Circle circle = new Circle(125, 125, 10, Color.WHITE);

        /* add items to the layout */
        pane.getChildren().add(circle);

        layout.setCenter(pane);
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
        stage.setWidth(300);
        stage.setHeight(300);
        stage.show();

        /* initialize custom Thread */
        ClassThread thread = new ClassThread(pane);
        thread.execute();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

...and the "thread class"

```
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;

public class ClassThread implements Runnable {

    private Thread t;
    private Pane pane;

    ClassThread(Pane p) {
        this.pane = p;

        t = new Thread(this, "Painter");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            Circle circle = new Circle(50, 50, 10, Color.RED);
            pane.getChildren().clear();
            pane.getChildren().add(circle);

        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void execute() {
        t.start();
    }
}
```

However, such a solution, where in Swing application could be possible, in JavaFX is impossible, and what's more, is the reason of the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "Painter" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Painter
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.clear(Unknown Source)
    at ClassThread.run(ClassThread.java:21)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

...where the line "21" is: `pane.getChildren().clear();`

I've concluded, that "there is a problem with influencing the main JavaFX thread from the level of another thread". But in this case, how can I change the JavaFX GUI elements shape and content dynamically, if I can't (tbh more accurately to say will be "I don't know how") bind togheter few threads?

**UPDATE : 2014/08/07, 03:42**

After reading given answers I tried to implement given solutions in code, in order to display 10 custom `Circle`s on different locations with specified time intervals between each display:

```
/* in ClassApplication body */
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    stage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
    stage.setWidth(300);
    stage.setHeight(300);
    stage.show();

    Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int random = r.nextInt(200) + 25;
        KeyFrame f = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis((i + 1) * 1000), 
            new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent ae) {
                pane.getChildren().add(new Circle(
                    random, random, 10, Color.RED));
            }
        });
        timeline.getKeyFrames().add(f);
    }
    timeline.setCycleCount(1);
    timeline.play();
}
```

The solution above works just fine. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In addition to using the low-level `Thread` API and `Platform.runLater(...)` to schedule code to be executed on the FX Application Thread, as in Tomas' answer, another option is to use the FX concurrency API. This provides `Service` and `Task` classes, which are intended to be executed on background threads, along with callback methods which are guaranteed to be executed on the FX Application Thread.

For your simple example, this looks like a bit too much boilerplate code, but for real application code it is quite nice, providing a clean separation between the background task and the UI update that is performed on completion. Additionally, `Task`s can be submitted to `Executor`s.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task ;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ClassApplication extends Application {

    private Pane pane;

    public Parent createContent() {

        /* layout */
        BorderPane layout = new BorderPane();

        /* layout -> center */
        pane = new Pane();
        pane.setMinWidth(250);
        pane.setMaxWidth(250);
        pane.setMinHeight(250);
        pane.setMaxHeight(250);
        pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #000000;");

        /* layout -> center -> pane */
        Circle circle = new Circle(125, 125, 10, Color.WHITE);

        /* add items to the layout */
        pane.getChildren().add(circle);

        layout.setCenter(pane);
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
        stage.setWidth(300);
        stage.setHeight(300);
        stage.show();

        Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() throws Exception {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                return null ;
            }
        };

        task.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
            Circle circle = new Circle(50, 50, 10, Color.RED);
            pane.getChildren().setAll(circle);
        });

        new Thread(task).run();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

If all you are doing is pausing, you can even get away with using (or abusing?) the animation API. There's a `PauseTransition` that pauses for a specified time, and you can use its `onFinished` handler to execute the update:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.animation.PauseTransition ;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration ;

public class ClassApplication extends Application {

    private Pane pane;

    public Parent createContent() {

        /* layout */
        BorderPane layout = new BorderPane();

        /* layout -> center */
        pane = new Pane();
        pane.setMinWidth(250);
        pane.setMaxWidth(250);
        pane.setMinHeight(250);
        pane.setMaxHeight(250);
        pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #000000;");

        /* layout -> center -> pane */
        Circle circle = new Circle(125, 125, 10, Color.WHITE);

        /* add items to the layout */
        pane.getChildren().add(circle);

        layout.setCenter(pane);
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
        stage.setWidth(300);
        stage.setHeight(300);
        stage.show();

        PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(2000));
        pause.setOnFinished(event -> pane.getChildren().setAll(new Circle(50, 50, 10, Color.RED)));
        pause.play();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

If you need to execute the pause multiple times, you can use a `Timeline`, and call `setCycleCount(...)`:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.animation.Timeline ;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration ;

public class ClassApplication extends Application {

    private Pane pane;

    public Parent createContent() {

        /* layout */
        BorderPane layout = new BorderPane();

        /* layout -> center */
        pane = new Pane();
        pane.setMinWidth(250);
        pane.setMaxWidth(250);
        pane.setMinHeight(250);
        pane.setMaxHeight(250);
        pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #000000;");

        /* layout -> center -> pane */
        Circle circle = new Circle(125, 125, 10, Color.WHITE);

        /* add items to the layout */
        pane.getChildren().add(circle);

        layout.setCenter(pane);
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
        stage.setWidth(300);
        stage.setHeight(300);
        stage.show();

        KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(2000), 
            event -> pane.getChildren().setAll(new Circle(50, 50, 10, Color.RED)));
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(keyFrame);

        // Repeat 10 times:
        timeline.setCycleCount(10);

        timeline.play();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: And if the abuse of the animation API is still too much boilerplate, ReactFX has a [wrapper](http://www.reactfx.org/javadoc/org/reactfx/util/FxTimer.html) around it: `FxTimer.runLater(Duration.ofMillis(2000), () -> pane.getChildren().setAll(new Circle(50, 50, 10, Color.RED)));`

Comment: @James_D The problem with this solution is that, it is good for a single delayed events. But in case of displaying multiple `Circle`s in specific intervals of time it's problematic. Say, I have 10 `Circle`s and I want them to be displayed one-by-one in, e.g. 2000ms intervals on the same `Pane`. I also tried to use `Timeline` and it's `KeyValue` and `KeyFrame`, but the problem is, that in `KeyValue` object I can't add and remove elements from the `Pane`.

Comment: Added an example which repeats 10 times. You can set the cycle count to `Animation.INDEFINITE` to repeat indefinitely. And @TomasMikula no doubt has a one-liner from ReactFX for the same thing ;).

Comment: @James_D To repeat indefinitely, just change `runLater` in my previous comment to `runPeriodically`. I don't have an easier solution for a fixed number of repetitions. I imagine something like this: `EventStreams.ticks(Duration.ofMillis(2000)).limit(10).subscribe(x -> pane.getChildren().setAll(new Circle(50, 50, 10, Color.RED)))`, except the `limit` operator is not there. It's just no one has asked for it yet :)

Comment: @James_D, @Tomas Mikula, I've tried to implement your solutions in some piece of code in my question update, but I have another small problem with the multiple custom `KeyFrame` initialization, adding, and execution in the `Timeline` object. The problem is, that specified `EventHandler`s works fine, but the `Duration` value is respected only for one of the added `KeyFrame`.

Comment: @bluevoxel In your code, you are adding 10 `KeyFrame`s, all of which execute at time=1000ms. If you want to use 10 key frames instead of 10 cycles, then use `Duration.millis((i+1) * 1000)`. KeyFrame's duration is paradoxically not duration of the KeyFrame, but duration since the start of the animation.

Comment: @James_D in your task.setOnSucceeded() the event handler is modifying the scene directly. According to the documentation, you should call Platform.runLater():  "Generally, Tasks should not interact directly with the UI. Doing so creates a tight coupling between a specific Task implementation and a specific part of your UI. However, when you do want to create such a coupling, you must ensure that you use Platform.runLater so that any modifications of the scene graph occur on the FX Application Thread." Is setOnSucceeded() exempt from this stipulation?

Comment: @Phil No: you have fundamentally misunderstood the documentation. The `Task` is not interacting with the UI. The event handler is.

Comment: @Phil Also from the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Task.html): *"Because the Task is designed for use with JavaFX GUI applications, it ensures that every change to its public properties, **as well as change notifications for state**, errors, and for event handlers, all occur on the main JavaFX application thread."* (My emphasis)

Answer (score 7):

You can access the scene only from the JavaFX application thread. You need to wrap your code that accesses the scene graph in `Platform.runLater()`:

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    Circle circle = new Circle(50, 50, 10, Color.RED);
    pane.getChildren().clear();
    pane.getChildren().add(circle);
});
```